# Change font size of a jQuery Mobile button at runtime

Tags: jquery, mobile, button, font-size

jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 changes how buttons are formed. Previously, I could set the font size of buttons like this:

```
<div id="Button1" data-role='button' data-inline=true data-theme=c 
 data-icon=false data-iconpos=none style="font-size:12px;">Button</div>
```

The font size attribute is being ignored in 1.1.1. It draws with the default font size (16px?). I can change the font size by adding this line of code:

```
$('#Button1').children().children().css('font-size','12px');
```

But now the vertical alignment of the text is off: it aligns with the original font size text's lower boundary.

Any ideas?

Comment: Noticing the same problem: font-size getting ignored in JQM1.1.1. I was trying to increase the font size of buttons, since the default size appears too small on a 3.1'' physical screen. I can increase the button height, but the fonts are not scaling, and font-size is not having any effect. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sets the font size:

```
$('#Button1').children().children().css('font-size','12px')
```

To center the text, you will also want to change the padding:

```
$('#Button1').children().css('padding','6px')
```

(tested with jQuery Mobile 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

I think the conflict in font-size may be with whichever line-height jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 is setting. Will this fix it?

```
$('#Button1').children().children().css('font-size','12px').css('line-height','12px');
```

**Edit** - try setting line-height in the css, for all children of the #Button element:

```
#Button1 *
{
    font-size:12px !important;
    line-height:12px !important;
}
```

Comment: With 1.2, this sets the font size:   $('#Button1').children().children().css('font-size','12px')

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I have found so far is adding { padding: 5px; } for the specific buttons. This works and the text is vertically aligned, but a second layer shows up around the button text. Don't know how to get rid of that.

See this [thread which discusses the solution](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/change-button-size).