# change font size of button text in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have 2 jQuery mobile buttons inside a `fieldset` and would like to change the `font-size` of one of the buttons. I have tried adding an inline style but that did not work.

I have also tried this but that did not work as-well:

```
.myButton
{
   word-wrap: break-word !important;
   white-space: normal !important;
}
```

This is what is happening: (only on the iPhone)

[image]

Because the screen size of the iPhone, the "Request Change" button is being cut-off.

**Is there a way for me to change the `font-size` of the button text so that it shows the complete text without getting cut-off?**

**HTML:**

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <input data-mini="true" type="submit" value="Cancel"  name="Submitbutton" class="button button-link"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <input data-mini="true" data-theme="b" type="submit" value="Request Change" name="Submitbutton" class="button button-link" /> 
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**I have tried:**

- [jquery mobile button text auto line break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351891/jquery-mobile-button-text-auto-line-break)
- [Change font size of a jQuery Mobile button at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657687/change-font-size-of-a-jquery-mobile-button-at-runtime)

Comment: Have you tried using `%` for `font-size` values?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. No luck :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Play with the following to find what's best on the iPhone screen

​

```
.ui-btn-inner{
    text-overflow: initial; /* Get rid of the ellipsis */
    padding-left: 5px; /* Play with padding to make max use of available button width */
}
.ui-btn-text {
    font-size: 15px; /* Play with font size of the text */
}
```

Comment: @Nirmal Patel :  should this be *text-overflow: inherit;* instead of *initial*?

Comment: the problem with this is that it affects all buttons

Comment: initial or clip (default for text-overflow)

Comment: For styling only particular buttons, make these styles specific to a parent container for your buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Pjvvx/ (Width)
- http://jsfiddle.net/3DSGT/ (Height)

JS:

```
// For all buttons use something like this
$('.ui-btn').css('width','50%');

// For individual buttons use something like this
$('#theButton1').parent().css('width', '75%');

// Or this for HREF data-role buttons
$('#hrefButton4').css('width', '45%');

// this changes the height for all buttons
$('.ui-btn-text').css('font-size','50px');

// This changes the height for a single element 
$('#hrefButton3').children().children().css('font-size','30px');
```

I think you're looking to do something like this:

```
$('#hrefButton3').children().children().css('font-size','10px');
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="button" id="theButton1" value="Press Me 1" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton2" value="Press Me 2" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton3" value="Press Me 3" />
        <input type="button" id="theButton4" value="Press Me 4" />
        <br />
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton1">HREF Me 1</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton2">HREF Me 2</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton3">HREF Me 3</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="hrefButton4">HREF Me 4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Related:

- [resizing a BUTTON through CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303035/resizing-a-button-through-css)

Comment: This was a good solution but in my case, Nirmal's solution worked better for me. Thanks for your help :)