# Jquery Mobile button even more small

Tags: css, templates, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [resizing a BUTTON through CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303035/resizing-a-button-through-css)

In Jquery mobile a **button** can be created with:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button"                  >Yes</a>
```

A **mini button** can be created with **data-mini="true"**:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Yes</a>
```

How can I create a button even more small?
*(I know jquery mobile don't have for default a button even more small) (I just need it)*

Comment: maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11673307/1546946

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to override the default css-style for the button size and add to your own CSS class which you then could set on the buttons you want smaller:

Css:

```
/* These values can be changed to preferred sizes */
.ui-mini.ui-mini-smaller .ui-btn-inner {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: .45em 10px .4em;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-mini="true" class="ui-mini-smaller">Yes</a>
```

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/XVJem/3/

Comment: The `!important` flag is not necessary if you properly scope your selector: `.ui-mini.ui-mini-smaller .ui-btn-inner` for instance. Also the button size is set by two properties, `font-size` and `padding`, so if you want to create a different size button those are your two properties to change.

Comment: Thank you. This  is exactly what i was searching.